# Commands inside textbf

Tags: macros, bold, math-fonts

I was working on creating a small table of formulas for my Math class. Since I will be using a lot of vector related stuff I defined and redefined some commands to suit my needs. Below you see my commands

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\textbf{#1}} %Vector
\newcommand{\scalar}[2]{\langle \vec{#1},\vec{#2} \rangle} %Scalar
\newcommand{\crossp}[2]{\vec{#1} \times \vec{#2}} %Crossproduct
```

The problem is that using the following code results in strange behaviour I do not understand and cannot find any help on.

```
\begin{equation}
        V = \scalar{u}{\crossp{v}{w}}
\end{equation}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

I have also tried using `\textbf{...}` directly, without using the vec function.
I know that `\vec` is basically obsolete, but I use it so I can see what is bold text and what are vectors when reading my code.
The problem is also not resulting from applying vec twice, as I have also tried simple inserting `v \times w`, which produces the exact same behaviour.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and propose a fix?

Thanks in advance.
Mike

Comment: \textbf is as the name indicates for text and not for math.

Comment: I wouldn't say `\vec` is basically obsolete, your command (with egreg's correction) is a great idea. As you say, it makes your input a bit more sane and reasonable and it allows you to change the way you notate vectors with one trivial edit. If you decide you wanna switch from bold to the arrow above you can do it instantly (although it might be a tad more complicated with your additional derivative commands to swap from boldface to an arrow above but yeah, still!)

Comment: if you get an error you should ask about the error message not show the typeset output (the pdf output isn't intended to be usable after an error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fix is simple: use `\mathbf` and not `\textbf`:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

Your code produces errors, the first of which is

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10         V = \scalar{u}{\crossp{v}{w}}
```

because `\textbf` enters text mode.

Even if that would be solvable you'd get in real trouble with something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\textbf{#1}} %Vector

\begin{document}

A vector $\vec{v}$.

\begin{theorem}
A vector $\vec{v}$.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you see the problem? This doesn't happen if you change `\textbf` into `\mathbf`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solved the problem.
I am new to LaTeX and didn't realize this would cause a problem - the more you know.